# exit command in shell

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am trying to write a shell in C language. I am trying to implement the exit command, but I am having problems getting the shell to execute commands before exit.

User Can Enters:

```
> quit 
> quit; cat file 
> cat file; quit
```

The shell needs to execute the cat file command in both lines before quitting.

This is what I currently have, but it's not completing the commands before exiting.

```
if(strstr(argument[0], "exit"))
{
    if(strcmp(argument[0],"exit")==0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    int i=0;
    while(argument[i] != '\0')
    {
        strcpy(&command[i], argument[i]);
        if(strcmp(command, "exit")==0){i++;}
        printf("Argument[i] = %s \n", command);
        execvp(command, argument);
        i++;
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You should read carefully about what `execvp` actually does, why you should not expect to be able to execute any of your code after calling it, and why it's usually used together with `fork()`.

Comment: Study the source code of existing free software shells. Use `strace` on them. Read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)

Answer (score 2):

You need a `fork-exec` mechanism of doing this. 
An `exec` family of functions will [replace the current process image with a new process image](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html). So when you exec out a program you will lose control of the calling program. If you wish to come back then you must `fork` a child, in which you can call an `execv` and make your parent wait until the child has terminated.

Here's a small snippet illustrating a `fork-exec`

```
int pid = my_fork();
if(pid == -1){
  printf("failed\n"); // We failed - bail out. 
}
else if(pid > 0){ // let the parent wait
 int status;
 waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
else{ // child
  execvp(command,argument); 
}
```

Comment: I've already implemented the fork-exec model, and it currently works with executing commands. The problem I'm having is implementing the built-in command "quit" into the shell. The shell won't execute commands when i enter  "quit; cat file" It will register it as "unrecognized command"

Comment: What does this print `printf("Argument[i] = %s \n", command);` in the case of `quit; cat file`?

Comment: It doesn't quite get there. When I try to enter quit; cat file it says command is not found through checking with execvp,.

Comment: However in the snippet in the question shows that your `printf` must execute before your`exec`